# Chrome browser opens but nothing happens after that in selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to figure out why selenium API's are not executing in chrome browser, while chromedriver and chrome version is identical.

Chromedriver Version -> 91.0.4472.19

Chrome Version-> 91.0.4472.124

**Output**: Chrome launches and "data;" comes written in URL Bar. Nothing happens after that and test continues in running state.

I have tested with chromedriver 89,90,91,92. But nothing seems to be working.

Have anyone faced this issue ever where chrome and chromdriver version were same but browser is not executing selenoum API?

Code:

Browser name is passed from testngXML file.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();
options.setBinary("C\\ProgramFiles(86)\\..\\chrome.exe"); (in this location, I have chrome 91)
.......
......
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe"); (Here I have chromedriver 91)
```

Comment: no, this seems strange, can you share your code how exactly did you try ?

Comment: Its nothing different. Its working in other machine. The next step is just to maximize browser and launch url.

Comment: hmm, I cannot comment on that until I see how exactly you are doing it

Comment: Its in client machine, I can not post from there.

Comment: @QualityMatters just try to show some dummy implementation?

Comment: Code added. But I dont think, it is going to help much, as this is a common code.

Comment: Getting any exception?

Comment: No, Its just keep running without doing anything

Comment: @QualityMatters, Have you solved it, Actually same is happening to me. same code working in DEV Vm but not in production VM. I have 103 Chrome.exe and Chrome browser. web site just opens but after Selenium API's are not executing.

Comment: @JackFrost For me, it was related to an admin policy where they disabled the "Inspect" feature from the browser. Once they enabled it, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to somehow chrome policies. In my corporate system, there was a policy adding in chrome browser from admin (In every 1 hour) which was marking "disableChromeDevToolBar" as true. This was making the inspect (ctrl+shift+I) also greyed out.

I tried to fix this part, by changing the "disableChromeDveToolBar" value from 1 to 0 ([Windor+r-> regedit-> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]).

This made the inspect and selenium API execution working in the chrome browser.

Note: I did not do any change in chrome browser and chromedriver. Issue was purely because of this policy.

Trying to get that policy detail from support team, if I can find out, I will update here.

Comment: That was a security policy which was restricting people to use scrapping and any kind of automation activity in browser.